# Running Microsoft Edge with C# From Windows Form (.NET Core) without crashing

Tags: c#

I am trying to run Microsoft Edge using C#

```
Process.Start("MicrosoftEdge.exe");
```

But as soon as Microsoft Edge opens it closes right after.

No idea how to fix this as I have little programming experience in c#

Comment: That _should_ work on its own so it sounds more like an Edge issue.  Can you open Edge without it crashing non programmatically?

Comment: Who told you that Edge executable name is "MicrosoftEdge.exe"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you entered an incorrect path.

I tried this and it works:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp23
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the accepted answer is correct,
This might not always work if the users computer is not in English.


Something like this should run the process directly and direct you to the given Url

`Process.Start("microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com.au");`